# Get values from dataset without column name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, dataset

I have a dataset filled with this excelsheet:

[image]

The method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowExcelFile(GetExcel model)
{
    DataSet result = null;
    var file = model.Files[0];
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // .xlsx
        IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(file.InputStream);

        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true; // if your first row contains column names
        result = reader.AsDataSet();
        reader.Close();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow data = result.Tables[0].Rows[i];
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(data.Table.Rows[i]["Column header name"]);
    }
    return View("ShowExcelFile");
}
```

---

If I replace "Column name" with "Amortization" I get all values in column F. But the values I want is in column K. If I write a "Column header name" in K1 I will get the values that way. But is there some way without using this? I don't wanna use a value in that column (most design issues for me).

So just for clarification: How do I get the values in cell K5:K10 with using the column header name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use index instead column names? Rows[i][ColumnIndex]

If you can use only Index try to use Rows[4][10]

```
result = reader.AsDataSet();
string CellValue=result.Tables[0].Rows[4][10];
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Oh must be my morning coffee havn't kicked in yet. So simple. Thank you!